# Delphi ClientDataSet Calculated field not updating for specific value

Tags: delphi, dataset, delphi-xe3, calculated-field

Can anyone please help me to figure out why a calculated field in ClientDataset is not updating with 0.1875. In fact it is not accepting 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0...etc. Field can be updated if value is 0.26, 0.51...0.1876..etc. I am using following code in Delphi XE3:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Close;
  DBEdit1.DataSource:= DataSource1;
  DBEdit1.DataField := 'PieceRate';
  ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('PieceRate').AsFloat :=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1PieceRateGetText(Sender: TField;
 var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  if Sender.IsNull then
   Text:='Why it is blank?'
  else
   Text:= Sender.Value;
end;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should post the field type and what SQL is filling up your dataset.

Comment: Your q needs an MCVE.  Also, why are you using a TDBEdit, which is to permit editing of a field value, with a calculated field?

Comment: When I press Calc button, I am just assigning Edit1.text value to calculated field. But it is not updating calculated field for 0.25, 0.50...etc.

Comment: In `ClientDataSet1PieceRateGetText` check to make certain you have a current row. I'm not sure how reliable `IsNull` will be for an empty dataset.

Comment: If it can accept 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28...etc then why not 0.25, 0.50, 0.75? See the screenshots  0.1874 & 0.1876 is working but not 0.1875.

Comment: That's the nature of buffer overflow and uninitialised data bugs. And it needn't be your code that's buggy (apart from perhaps trying to read values off a non-existent row). The DLL backing `TClientDataSet` has quite a few peculiar edge-case bugs.

Comment: The OP informs that the problematic field is a calculated field (I have removed the response because I erroneously post it as an answer instead of a comment).

Comment: I am hard coding the value to update calculated field. So does not matter what sql is written. I have used a random query: select 100 from employee in TSQLquery. No calculation on the basis of result of SQL.

Comment: To make shure to calculate the correct field you should use:
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSet.FieldByName('PieceRate').AsFloat :=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
end;

Comment: @Christine Ross I tried the same. Still not working. If I use DbGO (TADOquery) instead of DBExpress (TSQLquery/TclientDataset), ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('PieceRate').AsFloat :=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text) is working for 0.25 perfectly. Seems the bug in Delphi XE3 ClientDataSet.

Comment: For further guesses we need more information. I would not assume a bug, because you have to many numbers which work and work not. My alarm went up when I saw that you define the field as currency. It depends on the database, but they do sometimes unexpected things with currencies

Comment: @ChristineRoss: Readers should not have to guess, and should not be encouraged to leave their qs in a state which requires guesswork.  That's why I asked the OP for an MCVE, which he has so far failed to provide.

Comment: @MartynA have you ever heard from a concept called "irony". By the way what is the meaning of your abbrevations? Wikipedia gives following help for [OP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OP) and [MCVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCVE)

Comment: @ChristineRoss:  Yes I have, but it's not always easy to detect online.  What surprises me is that readers seem to be prepared to accept the OP's assertion without verification.  Is it really very likely that the 21-year-old Delphi cannot deal with the value 0.5 being assigned to a currency field? OP and MCVE are two of the most frequent abbreviations on SO.  OP="Original Poster" and MCVE = "Minimal Complete and verifiable example".  SO = err ...

Answer (score 3):

As you haven't provided an MCVE, I created my own, and its code and DFM extract
are below.  Its operation should be self-evident - it sets the `Value` calculated
field to the selected value in the ListBox.  The point of the ListBox's OnClick
handler calling `ClientDataSet.First` is to cause the dataset to scroll and so
invoke its OnCalcFields event.

The project does NOT exhibit the problem you allege (though it's unclear what
exactly you mean by the value not being "accepted").  Whichever item in the ListBox
is clicked, the corresponding currency value is displayed in the DBEdit preceded
by the system's curency symbol, the only minor exception being that 0.1875
is displayed as "£0.19" because by default the value is rounded to two decimal places.  My program operates identically in D7 and D10 Seattle, btw.

So, whatever is causing your problem is something in your project that you've not
included in your q, which shows if nothing else the value of an MCVE.

In a comment you said:

> When I press Calc button, I am just assigning Edit1.text value to calculated field.

Well, that's not what your Button1Click handler does, according to the code in your q.  If you *are* assigning a value to the calculated field anywhere else than in the OnCalcFields event you should be checking that your dataset is in the appropriate `State` (`TDataSetState`) before you do so.  Are you?

Code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBEdit1: TDBEdit;
    ClientDataSet1ID: TIntegerField;
    ClientDataSet1Value: TCurrencyField;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure ClientDataSet1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Value').AsString := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([1]);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.First;
end;
```

DFM extract

```
object DBEdit1: TDBEdit
  DataField = 'Value'
  DataSource = DataSource1
end
object ListBox1: TListBox
  Items.Strings = (
    '0'
    '0.1875'
    '0.25'
    '0.50'
    '0.75'
    '1.0')
  OnClick = ListBox1Click
end
object ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet
  Aggregates = <>
  Params = <>
  OnCalcFields = ClientDataSet1CalcFields
  object ClientDataSet1ID: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'ID'
  end
  object ClientDataSet1Value: TCurrencyField
    FieldKind = fkCalculated
    FieldName = 'Value'
    Calculated = True
  end
end
object DataSource1: TDataSource
  DataSet = ClientDataSet1
end
```